# How do I group by sequence in LINQ?

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, linq-to-objects

Given sequence :

```
["1","A","B","C","2","F","K","L","5","6","P","I","E"]
```

The numbers represent items that I identify as headers, whereas the letters represent items that I identify as data. I want to associate them into groups like this.

```
1:A,B,C    
2:F,K,L    
5:    
6:P,I,E
```

I can easily achieve this using a foreach or while loop on the enumerator, but is there a LINQ'ish way to achieve this? This is a recurring pattern in my domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of a fold:

```
var aggr = new List<Tuple<Int,List<String>>>();
var res = sequence.Aggregate(aggr, (d, x) => {
    int i;
    if (Int32.TryParse(x, out i)) {
        var newDict = d.Add(new Tuple(i, new List<string>()));
        return newDict;
    } 
    else {
        var newDict = d[d.Count - 1].Item2.Add(x);
        return newDict;
    }
}).ToDictionary(x => x.Item1, x => x.Item2);
```

However, this doesn't look so nice, since there's lacking support for immutable values. Also, I couldn't test this right now.

Comment: Interesting. I haven't used aggregate quite that much, though I recognize FoldR to be much used in Func prog. Time to investigate what it can do for me.

Comment: Yeah, it is very natural in functional programming, since every recursion can be translated into a fold. Which is nice if there's no `for` available. Btw, was my code working?

Comment: Yes, it did. Sorry for the delay. I replaced "new Tuple()" with Tuple.Create and consumed "d" directly without any "newDict". But yes, it worked. Thank you.

Comment: Wow. Read this and I think I just levelled up as a programmer.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution with LINQ. It's a little bit complicated though. There may be room for some tricks. It doesn't look that terrible but it can be more readable with a foreach loop.

```
int lastHeaderIndex = default(int);
Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>> groupedItems =
    items.Select((text, index) =>
                 {
                     int number;
                     if (int.TryParse(text, out number))
                     {
                         lastHeaderIndex = index;
                     }
                     return new { HeaderIndex = lastHeaderIndex, Value = text };
                 })
          .GroupBy(item => item.HeaderIndex)
          .ToDictionary(item => item.FirstOrDefault().Value,
                        item => item.Skip(1).Select(arg => arg.Value));
```

Comment: Yup, doesn't look too icky. I'll see if I can replace the first selector function with a named function (or a function accepting the captured variable and returning a selector function). I will probably use overload for GroupBy that allows a ResultSelector instead of the ToDictionary call. Then it will actually read pretty well.

Answer (score 2):

`foreach` loop with `int.TryParse` should help. 'GroupBy' from LINQ won't help here much.

Comment: Yup, that's what I meant by "while" loop. I edited to include foreach.

Answer (score 2):

Since this a common pattern in your domain, consider streaming the results instead of gathering them all into a large in-memory object.

```
public static IEnumerable<IList<string>> SplitOnToken(IEnumerable<string> input, Func<string,bool> isSplitToken)
{
    var set = new List<string>();
    foreach(var item in input)
    {
        if (isSplitToken(item) && set.Any())
        {
            yield return set;
            set = new List<string>();
        }
        set.Add(item);
    }
    if (set.Any())
    {
        yield return set;
    }
}
```

Sample usage:

```
var sequence = new[] { "1", "A", "B", "C", "2", "F", "K", "L", "5", "6", "P", "I", "E" };
var groups = SplitOnToken(sequence, x => Char.IsDigit(x[0]));

foreach (var @group in groups)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", @group[0], String.Join(" ", @group.Skip(1).ToArray()));
}
```

output:

```
1: A B C
2: F K L
5: 
6: P I E
```

Comment: The tools are offline batch jobs and the data is not huge. But it is something to consider. Especially since the start of a new group is a definite end of the previous, then the obvious knee jerk response SHOULD have been to yield it. I agree 100%. To expand further on the abstract, the function should accept a predicate to identify headers.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I ended up using. Pretty much the same structure as phg's answer.

Basically, it is an aggregate function that maintains a Tuple containing:
 1: the accummulated data. 
 2: state of the parser.

The aggregating function does an if-else to check if currently examined item is a group header or a regular item. Based on this, it updates the datastore (last part of the tuple) and/or changes the parser state (first part of the tuple).

In my case, the parser state is the currently active list (that upcoming items shall be inserted into).

```
var sequence = new[]{ "1","A","B","C","2","F","K","L","5","6","P","I","E"};
var aggr = Tuple.Create(new List<string>(), new Dictionary<int,List<string>>());
var res = sequence.Aggregate(aggr, (d, x) => {
    int i;
    if (Int32.TryParse(x, out i))
    {
        var newList = new List<string>();
        d.Item2.Add(i,newList);
        return Tuple.Create(newList,d.Item2);
    } else
    {
        d.Item1.Add(x);
        return d;
    }
},d=>d.Item2);
```